# React Native View is cut on iPhone XR

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm having trouble in Display on iPhone XR, the react native app is wrapped inside a screen margin which is not the case for iPhone XR, I tried the SafeAreaView but it changes nothing.

[image]

I'm using react-native-router-flux for navigation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add some of the code snipped?

Comment: My render function is simple : `render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }`